# Does C++11 allow a better way to repeat the same action on similar data without non-anonymous helper functions?

Tags: c++11

*(I really can't think of a better title, please help if you can)*

It's not unusual to have this kind of repetitive code... a deliberately simple example:

```
vector<int> x,y,z;
vector<string> a,b,c;

for(auto i : x)
 if(test(i))
  a.push_back(func(i));
for(auto i : y)
 if(test(i))
  b.push_back(func(i));
for(auto i : z)
 if(test(i))
  c.push_back(func(i));
```

You could of course write a function `Convert(const vector<int> &in, vector<string> &out)` however I was curious if there's a way you could use anonymous constructs or function-local definitions to avoid this.

Something like:

```
vector<int> x,y,z;
vector<string> a,b,c;

for(auto o : {{x,a},{y,b},{z,c}})
  ...
```

What would be the neatest way to do this - and *does* C++11 provide any additional help beyond a 'classic' C++/STL approach?

**Note: the point of this question is how to avoid repeating code, not how specifically to transform the data between the vectors - that's just a trivial example.**

Comment: Put x, y, z and a, b, c into arrays / vectors and use nested for-loops.

Comment: So put it into an answer... the details are important so sample code would be much more useful. And then people can vote on it

Comment: So your `for` has to automagically know if it has to stop after `min(a, b, c)` loops or `max(a, b, c)` loops? The compiler will need to analyze the repeated block in order to see if there are any relationships between `a`, `b` and `c`? And it has to know that, when there is no data fo push into `a` but there is still data to push into `b`, if it should do nothing with `a` or if it should push `0`?

Comment: @SJuan76 I don't really follow your question. My "suggestion" was merely one theoretical idea that doesn't work - because of lack of anonymous struct support AFAIK

Comment: @SJuan76 huh? min(a,b,c)/max(a,b,c) - what do you mean and why do you think this is important?

Comment: You could iterate on multiple containers at a time with boost's [zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html). However they are read-only (and this is very sad). Alternatively, there are  (or will be )[c++17 ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: @Drop, there will be a ranges TS, it's not going to be in C++17 though

Comment: @JonathanWakely on CppCon2015 they've said it will be almost for sure. Have they changed their mind?

Comment: @Drop who is "they"? The author of the proposal doesn't think it makes sense to rush it into C++17 and many of us on the committee agree.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that's sad =( For some reason after watching Eric Niebler's speach I had an impression that it's almost done.

Answer (score 6):

The classic STL way is to use `std::transform`, and you can wrap that in a lambda if you want to

```
auto map = [](const vector<int>& in, vector<string>& out, string (*f)(int)) {
  out.reserve(in.size());
  std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), f);
};

vector<int> x,y,z;
vector<string> a,b,c;

map(x, a, func);
map(y, b, func);
map(z, c, func);
```

In C++14 the lambda is easier to write:

```
auto map = [](const auto& in, auto& out, auto f) {
  out.reserve(in.size());
  std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), f);
};
```

To do the different operation in the edited question just change the body of the lambda, you still avoid repeating the logic, so you only define it once, then apply it to each pair of vectors:

```
auto op = [](const auto& in, auto& out, auto f) {
  for (auto i : in)
    if (test(i))
      out.push_back(f(i));
 };

op(x, a, func);
op(y, b, func);
op(z, c, func);
```

If you want to go to extremes in C++14 you can bundle the vectors up in tuples and use `apply` from the Library Fundamentals TS like so:

```
vector<int> x,y,z;
vector<string> a,b,c;

using std::experimental::apply;

auto mapper = [&func, &test](auto... t) {
  auto op = [](const auto& in, auto& out) {
    for (auto i : in)
      if (test(i))
        out.push_back(func(i));
   };
  std::tie( (apply(op, t), std::ignore) ... );
};
mapper( std::tie(x, a), std::tie(y, b), std::tie(z, c) );
```

But this is getting quite unreadable!

Comment: +1 You could probably further reduce duplication of `map` function call by grouping vectors into `std::tuple`s.

Comment: ... and without doing so, I don't think you're actually answering OP's question.

Comment: @davmac, the OP asks "if there's a way you could use anonymous constructs or function-local definitions to avoid [defining a function]" and that's exactly what a lambda does.

Comment: @JonathanWakely without defining _an explicit_ (i.e. named) function. Stuff local to the method is fine. However please post alternative approaches... I'd rather see several answers than have someone 'correct' their answer

Comment: Also: my example was meant to be generic rather than explicitly about that particular problem. I've modified it slightly to reflect what I'm actually trying to do and make it a little less of a special case - I'm not sure if this breaks the use of `transform`?

Comment: Well you'd just change the body of the lambda to do that instead of calling `transform`. The point of my answer is that yes, C++11 provides precisely the tool to use function-local definitions to do this kind of thing: lambda expressions.

Comment: No worries - I just didn't want to go the "how do I transform one container into another" route with this question, which my over-simplified example inadvertently lead to

Comment: @Drop, if you group them into tuples then you need some non-local function to "iterate" over the tuple. You could either write that yourself using `std::index_sequence` or use something like `std::experimental::apply` or Boost.Hana, but it can no longer be done purely with function-local definitions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was thinking more like about grouping iterators into tuples the way `zip_iterators` work in boost or thrust. This was just an idea, I use this often (structure-of-arrays idiom), but don't quite familiar how it is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @JonathanWakely not a major issue but in VS2013 I get "auto is not allowed here" defining  `auto map = [](const auto& in, auto& out)`. I have no idea if that's due to my specific code/types but wanted to double check this _should_ be valid?

Comment: @Mr.Boy it should be valid in C++14, but I expect VS2013 doesn't support generic C++14 lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

for me this works just fine:

```
vector<pair<vector<string>&,vector<int>&>> work{{a,x},{b,y},{c,z}};

for(auto w:work)
{
    for(auto i : w.second)
        if(test(i))
            w.first.push_back(func(i));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct to me. Your `func` isn't the same as mine, you pass `vector<int>` to it not `int` surely?

Comment: Please note my slight tweak to the logic, my initial example was too 'simple' I meant it to be a bit more generic

Comment: @Mr.Boy: adapted it to your new logic ;)